# Запятую или тире правильнее поставить между частями сложносочинённого предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Он больше не кричит, хуже – голос становится угрожающе тихим.

Или:

Он больше не кричит, хуже, голос становится угрожающе тихим?

Comment: Я бы поставил здесь двоеточие после 'хуже', поскольку дальше раскрывается, почему именно хуже.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь надо выбрать тире, оно лучше подходит по интонационным соображениям (нет увеличенной предупредительной паузы, характерной для пояснительного двоеточия):

*Он больше не кричит, хуже – **голос становится угрожающе тихим**.*

Это БСП, между первой и второй частью пояснительные отношения, их можно обозначить двоеточием или тире. Запятая не подойдет ввиду наличия паузы более значительной, чем при запятой.

Answer (score 0):

Между частями предложения достаточно запятой. Запятая нужна и для обособления вводного *хуже* (*хуже того*). Паузу можно обозначить и тире, и двоеточием, и восклицательным знаком.

> Или, хуже того, площадка для отстоя машин. [Передел именем Бирюлево //
> «Русский репортер», 2013]
>
> Или хуже того ― уволят ко всем чертям. [Сергей Дигол. Три фута под
> землей // «Волга», 2012]
>
> Хуже того: эти люди не осознают себя как отдельную группу со своими
> интересами, возможностями и инструментами влияния. [Ольга Балла, Борис
> Дубин. Учеба — одно, а жизнь — другое» // «Знание-сила», 2013]
>
> Хуже того! Теперь они могут стать бактериологическим оружием. [А.М.
> Городницкий. Тайны и мифы науки. В поисках истины (2014)]

В отсутствие *того* добавил бы союз и тире: «Он больше не кричит, и хуже, — голос становится угрожающе тихим».